# Help with if-then sentences in Predicate Logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I need help to translate some English sentences to predicate logic. I am able to translate sentences like "If no philosophers are happy, then some philosopher is wise." but I have no idea how to translate when a sentence is like "1 is more clever than 2" or "1 reads 2"

For example, let 
$$P(x): =\text{“x is a philosopher”; }$$ $$H(x): =\text{ “x is happy” ;}$$ $$C(a,b): = \text{“a is more clever than b” ;}$$

$$R(a,b):=\text {“a reads b”.} $$

How would these sentence translate into predicate logic in this instance?

1. No happy philosopher reads every wise philosopher.
2. All wise philosophers are read by some philosopher.
3. If Socrates reads every philosopher, then he reads every wise
   philosopher.
4. Not every wise philosopher fails to read some happy
   philosopher.
5. If not every happy philosopher is read by some philosopher, then
   some happy philosophers aren’t read by any philosopher.

   I would like to get explained answers rather than direct ones.
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, sorry W(x) = "x is wise" . C12 is not important I put it for example.

Comment: I'd love to help, but not until you show some effort on a few.  For example, list which quantifiers you think you'll need for $1-5$.  You'll need some more explanation and demonstrated effort on your questions before you should request explanations of all answers .

Comment: I will add my work. I didn't add it because I was not sure about correctness of them.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answers will be useful. I will try to translate others and put them here.

Comment: I couldn't figured out how to add answers with special characters.
∀ ∃ ∼ ⊃

Comment: There should be nothing stopping you from using words "for all", "there exits" (or, equivalently "some").  You've defined the predicates, You can use words to express "and", and words to express "then" or even use --> to denote implication.

Comment: I have tried to do these two. I couldn't figured out last one. 

2) ∀x(Px&Wx) & ∀y(Py&Wy) ⊃ Rxy)
4) ∼∀x (Px&Wx) & ∼∃y((Py&Hy) ⊃ Rxy)

Comment: I think you are right, I messed up a little. Sorry.

Comment: Okay: for (2) your start is correct $$\forall x\Big(\big(P(x)\land W(x)\big)\rightarrow \exists y(P(y) \land R(y, x))\Big)$$

Comment: I think for $(4)$, $$\lnot \forall x\Big((P(x) \land W(x))\rightarrow \exists y(P(y) \land H(y) \land \lnot R(x, y))\Big)$$

Comment: BTW `$\exists$` = $\exists$, `$\forall$`= $\forall$

Comment: Plus, you can always "right click" when you're hovering over a formatted expression, like in my last comment above, and then hover over "show math as", and then form the menu on the right, click on "Tex".  It will reveal all the formatting, minus the needed $ at each end.

Comment: Here is a link for latex:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics

All you do is add the dollar sign to both ends of the latex line, that's it. :)

Answer (score 2):

To get you started, I've translated directly, the first statement.

"No happy philosopher reads every wise philosopher."

$$\lnot \exists x \Big(P(x)\land H(x) \land \forall y\big((P(y) \land W(y))\rightarrow R(x, y)\big)\Big)\tag 1$$

$$\forall x\Big(\big(P(x)\land W(x)\big)\rightarrow \exists y(P(y) \land R(y, x))\Big)\tag 2$$

You can also define constants that *name* a specific individual.  For the third question, I'll use $s$ to name "Socrates".

"If Socrates reads every philosopher, then he reads every wise philosopher."

$$\forall x, \Big((P(x) \rightarrow R(s,x))\Big) \rightarrow \forall y\Big(\big((W(y) \land P(y))\rightarrow R(s, y)\big)\Big)\tag 3$$

$$\lnot \forall x\Big((P(x) \land W(x))\rightarrow \exists y(P(y) \land H(y) \land \lnot R(x, y))\Big)\tag 4$$

Comment: Feel free to ask any question you have about these two translations, in this comment section, or to post inhere any attempt you've made that you'd like me to check.

Answer (score 0):

For question 5:$
\lnot \forall x \Big(P(x)\land H(x) \rightarrow \exists y(P(y) \land R(x,y))\big) \rightarrow \Big(\exists x (P(x)\land H(x)) \rightarrow (\forall y P(y) \rightarrow \lnot R(x,y))\Big) \tag 5$

Answer (score 0):

If $P(x)$ means that $x$ is a philosopher, than negating the same predication means $x$ is not a philosopher, i.e. $\lnot P(x)$  means "x is not a philosopher".

If you want to work with one philosopher, you use the **existential** quantifier.  For a relation that holds for an arbitrary case or all cases, you use the **universal** quantifier.  The negation of an existential quantifier is universal, and vice versa.  The rule though, is that you distribute the negation across the quantifiers to the statements (when proving theorems using the contrapositive, etc).

For every element of the domain, the predication holds such that:

$\forall x(...x...)$

For every element of the domain, there is **one** element such that the predication holds:

$\exists x(...x...)$

So when you start symbolozing relations, look for the signs that the property or relation is for any, for all, for one, or for none.

Here is an example:
"All philosphers dislike Kant"

The key is to notice how many are doing what, and what the relationship is.  The "all" makes the quantifier for philosophers easy, we'll use $P$ as the predication for philosopher and $P(x)$ for "x is a philosopher."  Since Kant is a proper noun, we could use a single capital letter, but realize this is a different order logic!  We'll add a lower case variable instead.  Let $y$ be Kant.  The relation between Kant and philosophers is that they all dislike Kant.  So the relation is between all philosophers and Kant.  The relation to Kant is also a "no," or negative relation so we'll need to negate something.  Now there was only one Kant (thankfully, amiright?) so we use the existential for any predications of $y$.  We'll set $L$ for "likes."

We can then say:

$ \forall x \exists y \ [(Px \uparrow Ky) \implies \lnot Lxy]$

We can use $K$ to stand for Kant, which simplifies the statement, otherwise you would need to refine the predication of $y$ to be:

$\exists y (Py \uparrow Ky)$

For, "There is a philosopher, and that philosopher is Kant."

The standard "if-then" conditionals hinge on the truth table of the conditional operator.  If the consequent is true, the antecedent can be true *or* false.  If the antecedent is true, then the consequent *must be* true for the *conditional operator* to be true.

"If you are a philosopher, then you hate Kant.  All philosophers hate Kant."

$\forall x \exists y \ [Px \implies (\lnot Lxy \uparrow Ky) ]$

When you move to more advanced predicate calculus you'll want to take care in how often you combine the universal and existential quantifiers for single propositions like theorems.  You'll also want to be aware of which variables are existential or universal.

Now we'll moved to **ordered relations**.  A relation that is *reflexive* uses an ordered pair of variables sharing the same predication.  For example, only clever philosophers like Kant.  Using the same notation as before, but now introducing $C$ for "clever" and $Cxy$ for "x is more clever than y" we can symbolize this as:

$\forall (x)(z) \exists (y) \ [(Px \uparrow Pz ) \implies \lnot Lxy] \downarrow [(Pz \uparrow Czx) \implies Lzy]$

This symbolizes the statement:

> "There are two types of philosophers, those who don't like Kant or those who are more clever and like Kant."

Hope this helps!

Here is a [link](https://math.berkeley.edu/~sagrawal/su14_math55/notes_quantifiers.pdf) to a two page pdf about quantifiers hosted at UC-Berkeley.

Comment: Is "$\uparrow$" supposed to be "and" ("$\wedge$")? And what does "$Pxy$" mean (isn't $P$ unary)? Finally, I think your last example has some formatting errors.

Comment: Yes, up arrow is the conjunction, down arrow is disjunction.  This is the notation I was taught.  I do see some hanging parentheses too, thank you.  And I did go too fast, Px and Py should be separated  Thanks for checking my work!

Comment: I think I have it all cleaned up now.